# catkin can't find PCLConfig.cmake

Tags: pcl, catkin, ros-hydro, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I did the standard catkin_create_pkg with PCL as a dependency and I'm getting this with catkin_make:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package PCL.

  Set PCL_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for PCL.
  The file will have one of the following names:

    PCLConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake

Call Sta-name>ck (most recent call first):
  <proj/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Just doing some basic file searching, I believe that all of the cmake config files are in /opt/ros/hydro/share - is that correct?

If so - here are a couple of directories that seem relevant:

```
ls -l /opt/ros/hydro/share/pcl
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1480 Jul 23 18:43 package.xml
```

---

```
ls -l /opt/ros/hydro/share/pcl-1.7/
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27024 Aug 23 15:37 PCLConfig.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   431 Aug 23 15:37 PCLConfigVersion.cmake
```

What should I do to catkin to make it realize these files are in front of its face?

Alternatively - how do I do the short term thing and night PCL_DIR? I tried this at one point above the find_packages line in my CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(pcl_DIR "/opt/ros/hydro/share/pcl-1.7/")
```

but it didn't do anything :(

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81306/catkin-can%27t-find-pclconfig.cmake/) by [ndepalma](https://answers.ros.org/users/4811/ndepalma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-19**:
You need to update your packages and explicitly remove the `ros-hydro-pcl` package, as of the official Hydro release the pcl debs should be `libpcl-1.7-all` and `libpcl-1.7-all-dev` rather than the old `ros-hydro-pcl` deb. You'll know you have the right one because files like the `PCLConfig.cmake` will be in `/usr/share` rather than `/opt/ros/hydro/share`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_create_pkg` does not take non-catkin packages as arguments by default, you must pass them as parameters to the `--sys-deps` argument. PCL is not a catkin package it is a system dependency on par with Boost and other external dependencies.

You can, however, depend on `pcl_ros` which pulls in `PCL` as a transitive dependency.

Otherwise, you will need to depend on `PCL` like this:

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
...
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
....
target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

The `pcl_ros` package's `CMakeLists.txt` is a good example of this:

https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/hydro-devel/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ndepalma](https://answers.ros.org/users/4811/ndepalma/) on 2013-09-24**:
Side question: what is keeping catkin from understanding how to find system level dependencies vs ros packages? Is this just to keep from getting into dependency hell?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-24**:
There is no consistency for finding system level packages. Some use `pkg-config`, others `cmake` and when they do use `cmake` they use widely different variable names and so we can't assume anything about system level dependencies, for example we can't know if the package provides us with `<pkg>_INCLUDE_DIRS` or `<pkg>_INCLUDE_DIR`.